# How to configure CruiseControl to trigger a build automatically on code check in

Tags: cruisecontrol

How can we configure cruisecontrol to automatically trigger a build on code check in? We are currently using CruiseControl 2.8.4 in Windows machine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read [this tutorial](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/DrivingOnCruiseControl_Part1.html).

In short you need to define a [modification set](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#modificationset) with a source code management like [svn](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#svn).

This will poll the repository in defined time intervals (e.g. `quietperiod="300"`(5 Minutes, 600 Seconds) for the modification set), it will not be instant.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. CruiseControl has to poll the SVN for changes.